# I have a Windows 10 Inspiron 7559 and it's running slow at start up and doesn't allow me to click on anything how can I fix this issue

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, lag, mouse-click, application-launch

I just recently picked the interest of working on computers. I currently own a Windows 10 Inspiron 7559 but when I first boot it up everything freezes and I can't click on anything even I plug in another mouse to use. I know how to do some of the basics troubleshooting, but it still does it and I can't figure out why. One of my buddies had tried helping me fix the issue but it didn't work but it did fix some of the performance issue. Now is there anything I can do to stop the lag or whatever the issue is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Everything you don't really use is not necessary. Just clean it up and see how you go. Don't delete drivers, and you'll be fine. If you are not sure about Windows Updates - don't remove them.

Comment: Darius,  I only ask because my when I first boot my laptop on and give it a minute or two to warm up. I won't be able to click or open anything even with an external mouse

Comment: If the machine is running at some point, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10     .   Start with the option Keep Everything.